# Get RSS feed from Youtube playlist in reverse order

Tags: youtube, rss, query

I subscribe to a few Youtube channels and playlists via RSS. To get the RSS feed of a playlist, (e.g. [Crash Course Philosophy](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8dPuuaLjXtNgK6MZucdYldNkMybYIHKR)), we get the playlists’ URL, and replace everything but the ID with a specific URL. In this case, `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8dPuuaLjXtNgK6MZucdYldNkMybYIHKR` becomes `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=PL8dPuuaLjXtNgK6MZucdYldNkMybYIHKR`.

This has been working fine, but today I hit a limitation. I noticed that specific feed got stuck on 15 items and no  longer updated. By looking at the other still-working feeds I subscribe to, it seems order of the playlist is the issue. To build the feed, Youtube basically gets only the latest 15 items in the playlist, and playlists are by default added from bottom to top (add a new item, it becomes the first). Since that particular playlist follows a top to bottom order (the newest item is always put at the bottom) and Youtube only checks 15 items from the top, it essentially thinks nothing else is being added.

The only solution I’m seeing to fix this with minimal disruption is if on the query parameters to build the RSS feed there was a way to specifically say it should be checked in reverse order. I’ve tried a bunch of them from both v2 and v3 of the documentation, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score -3):

have you tried using an RSS reader for the task? Just copy and paste the playlist URL to your reader, I use www.inoreader.com since it has the most features for free.

Comment: I use an RSS reader to read the feed. But read order is unimportant, what matters is what items the feed has. That can only be controlled by Youtube.